# Перебор после цикла и данные из цикла

Tags: c#

Простой цикл от 1 до 3

```
for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
}
```

но после того как цикл полностью весь прошел, то потом все числа в цикле перебираются типа так значит будет так:

```
1
2
3
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

проблема только с реализацией через массив комбинации, все остальное есть..
вот такой код настругал, но мне надо с начало цикл а потом комбинации.......

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string st = "123";
        for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
        {
            string main = st[i].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(main);
            string[] arr = { main };
            for (int j = 0; j < st.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < st.Length; k++)
                {
                    string stroka = j.ToString() + k.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(stroka);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Ну сделайте ещё два вложенных цикла.

Comment: @VladD я кинул образец, но все равно не то что мне надо, мб есть какие нибудь еще варианты ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такое:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 3; ++x)
    for (int y = 1; y <= 3; ++y)
        Console.WriteLine(10 * x + y);
```